# Cancel merge without merge commit and rebase

Tags: git

I'm looking for way how to fix this issue I run to:

I have branch  "develop" and branch "feature-1"

I'm merging "feature-1" to develop and continue work on it.

Now I've done mistake and created "feature-2" branch which points to "feature-1" not "develop" and push changes to server

```
D1 - D2 - D3 - D4 - D5
    \        /
     F1 - F2 - F3 - F4
                   \
                    F21 - F22
```

Now I want to merger "feature-2" to "develop"
I use merge which also merge F3 commit, but didn't create merge commit (don't know why)

so I have this:

```
D1 - D2 - D3 - D4 - - - - - - D5
    \        /                /
     F1 - F2 - F3 - F4       /
                   \        /
                    F21 - F22
```

I wan't to revert this and rebase feature-2 to develop

to have this:

```
                  F21 - F22
                  /      \
D1 - D2 - D3 - D4 - - - - D5 
    \        /                
     F1 - F2 - F3 - F4
```

How can I revert that merge if there is no merge commit and fix this also on server.

Comment: So you want develop to point to D4 and feature-2 to be taken out from maybe D4 and then add commits F21 and F22 and then merge it with develop? Just confirming.

Comment: Well I want to develop to point D5 and F4, but be able to merge feature-2 (F21,F22) to multiple branches without merging feature-1 (...F4).
I know ho to do it ```git rebase --onto develop feature-1 feature-2```, but feature-2 is already merged on develop with feature-1 changes and there is not commit to revert. I clone again whole repo for fix this. But still would like to know answer.

Comment: Easiest solution I would have done is, reset develop to D4 by `reset --hard`. Create new feature 2 branch (lets call it f2-branch) from this. Then cherry pick commits F21 - F22 on this newly created branch. You now f22 branch with only branch 2 commits. Let me know if you want me to convert this to detailed answer.

Comment: I run into same issue today :D
fix it like this: ```git reset --hard origin/develop``` which cancel merge commits which are not shown in log. And than rebase feature branch ```git rebase --onto develop feature-1 feature-2``` and force push ```git push origin feature-2 --force``` now I can merge this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer:

1. reset `develop` branch to origin state, to cancel merge commit which are not in git log

   git reset --hard origin/develop
2. move `feature-2` to point to master not feature-1

   git rebase --onto develop feature-1 feature-2
3. rewrite origin state of branch

   git push origin feature-2 --force
4. merge feature-2 to develop

   git merge feature-2

another solution would be like @Vishwanath mentioned in comment cherry pick, wanted commits to new branch from develop.